# IOS Safari iPad input file multiple locks up the use of the camera for other uses

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, ios-camera

I'm facing a problem with my web app on Safari iPad. I have an input type of file multiple to choose pictures from library and take a picture directly with the camera.
Here is the code:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
</body>
</html>
```

After taking a picture directly with the camera it seems to have a lock on the camera because I have an another button in my web app to scan a QRCode and it returns an error. I have to exit safari and restart it to be able to scan a QRCode again.

You can test with my code snippet, taking a picture with the camera and in another tab go to this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zn15Lufj/ based on the QRCode scan library https://cozmo.github.io/jsQR/ you will see that it cannot access to the camera (if you use the cozmo demo page it selects front camera because the rear camera is not accessible).

I tried on several iPad devices with IOS version 12.1.1. I don't have this problem on iPhone.

Is it possible to kill all process that access or lock the camera ?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I made my Minecraft pe folder TRASH
by putting hopscotch folder into it.

Comment: Koskeoosoeooosoosoooeosooosoosooosooso